# How can I arrange data from wide format to long format, and specify relationships

Tags: r, reshape

Currently I have a file which I need to converted from wide format to long format. The example of the data is:

```
Subject,Cat1_Weight,Cat2_Weight,Cat3_Weight,Cat1_Sick,Cat2_Sick,Cat3_Sick
1,10,11,12,1,0,0
2,7,8,9,1,0,0
```

However, I need it in the long format as follows

```
Subject,CatNumber,Weight,Sickness
1,1,10,1
1,2,11,0
1,3,12,0
2,1,7,1
2,2,8,0
2,3,9,0
```

So far I have tried in R to use the melt function

```
datalong <- melt(exp2_simon_shortform, id ="Subject")
```

But it treats every single column name as a unique variable each with its own value. Does anybody know how I could get from wide to long as specified, making reference to the column header names?

Cheers.

EDIT: I've realised I made an error. My final output needs to be as follows. So from the Cat1_ portion, I actually need to get out "Cat" and "1"

```
Subject Animal  CatNumber   Weight  Sickness
1   Cat 1   10  1
1   Cat 2   11  0
1   Cat 3   12  0
2   Cat 1   7   1
2   Cat 2   8   0
2   Cat 3   9   0
```

Any updated solutions much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, and to be honest, it is a relatively minor adjustment to the question. I imagine people searching for a solution to this problem won't be hindered by my update. But to apologize for this, I am new to Stack norms.

Comment: No problem, I updated the solutioin.

Answer (score 4):

The "dplyr" + "tidyr" approach might be something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
  gather(var, val, -Subject) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("CatNumber", "variable")) %>%
  spread(variable, val) 
#   Subject CatNumber Sick Weight
# 1       1      Cat1    1     10
# 2       1      Cat2    0     11
# 3       1      Cat3    0     12
# 4       2      Cat1    1      7
# 5       2      Cat2    0      8
# 6       2      Cat3    0      9
```

Add a `mutate` in there along with `gsub` to remove the "Cat" part of the "CatNumber" column.

---

#### Update

Based on [the discussions in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94575/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-michael-anderson), your data actually look something more like:

```
A = c("ATCint", "Blank", "None"); B = 1:5; C = c("ResumptionTime", "ResumptionMisses")

colNames <- expand.grid(A, B, C)
colNames <- sprintf("%s%d_%s", colNames[[1]], colNames[[2]], colNames[[3]])

subject = 1:60

set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(sample(10, length(subject) * length(colNames), TRUE), 
            nrow = length(subject), dimnames = list(NULL, colNames))

mydf <- data.frame(Subject = subject, M)
```

Thus, you will need to do a few additional steps to get the output you desire. Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>%                    ## Your ID variable
  gather(var, val, -Subject) %>%           ## Make long data. Everything except your IDs
  separate(var, into = c("partA", "partB")) %>%  ## Split new column into two parts
  mutate(partA = gsub("(.*)([0-9]+)", "\\1_\\2", partA)) %>% ## Make new col easy to split
  separate(partA, into = c("A1", "A2")) %>%                  ## Split this new column
  spread(partB, val)                                         ## Transform to wide form
```

Which yields:

```
Source: local data frame [900 x 5]

   Subject     A1    A2 ResumptionMisses ResumptionTime
     (int)  (chr) (chr)            (int)          (int)
1        1 ATCint     1                9              3
2        1 ATCint     2                4              3
3        1 ATCint     3                2              2
4        1 ATCint     4                7              4
5        1 ATCint     5                7              1
6        1  Blank     1                4             10
7        1  Blank     2                2              4
8        1  Blank     3                7              5
9        1  Blank     4                1              9
10       1  Blank     5               10             10
..     ...    ...   ...              ...            ...
```

Comment: Woot.. 100K! That's come up quick!

Comment: Google tells me that party is raging on until next week :-)

Comment: Thank you so so much for your response. Just trying to decipher it now. 

What does the \\2_\\1" do in the merged.stack?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, in the `gsub` step, that basically changes your column names from "Cat1_Weight" to "Weight_Cat1". The `"(.*)_(.*)"` says to look for groups of anything up to an underscore followed by another group of anything. We then replace it with the second group first (`\\2`) followed by an underscore, and then the first group (`\\1`). Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: @ananda-mahto Thank you, sorry would you be able to take a look at the edit to my question and see if you can adapt a solution?

Comment: Congrats on the 100K!

Comment: @akrun, thanks! I crawled here relative to some other people I know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `melt` from `library(data.table)` which can take multiple `patterns` for `measure` variable.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
DT <- melt(setDT(df1), measure=patterns('Weight$', 'Sick$'), 
            variable.name='CatNumber', value.name=c('Weight', 'Sick'))[order(Subject)]
DT 
#   Subject CatNumber Weight Sick
#1:       1         1     10    1
#2:       1         2     11    0
#3:       1         3     12    0
#4:       2         1      7    1
#5:       2         2      8    0
#6:       2         3      9    0
```

If we need the 'Animal' column, we can `grep` for 'Cat' columns and remove the suffix substring with `sub`, assign (`:=`) it to create the 'Animal' column.

```
DT[, Animal := sub('\\d+\\_.*', '', grep('Cat', colnames(df1), value=TRUE))]

DT
#   Subject CatNumber Weight Sick Animal
#1:       1         1     10    1    Cat
#2:       1         2     11    0    Cat
#3:       1         3     12    0    Cat
#4:       2         1      7    1    Cat
#5:       2         2      8    0    Cat
#6:       2         3      9    0    Cat
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with base `reshape`, like:

```
reshape(dat, idvar="Subject", direction="long", varying=list(2:4,5:7),
        v.names=c("Weight","Sick"), timevar="CatNumber")

#    Subject CatNumber Weight Sick
#1.1       1         1     10    1
#2.1       2         1      7    1
#1.2       1         2     11    0
#2.2       2         2      8    0
#1.3       1         3     12    0
#2.3       2         3      9    0
```

Alternatively, since `reshape` expects names like `variablename_groupname` you could change the names then get reshape to do the hard work:

```
names(dat) <- gsub("Cat(.+)_(.+)", "\\2_\\1", names(dat))
reshape(dat, idvar="Subject", direction="long", varying=-1, 
        sep="_", timevar="CatNumber")

#    Subject CatNumber Weight Sick
#1.1       1         1     10    1
#2.1       2         1      7    1
#1.2       1         2     11    0
#2.2       2         2      8    0
#1.3       1         3     12    0
#2.3       2         3      9    0
```

Comment: You forced me to write a "dplyr" answer. +1

Comment: Cheers for the response. In terms of changing names - what should I do in the case of my real variable names which are:
"ATCint[1:5]_ResumptionTime"
"Blank[1:5]_ResumptionTime"
"None[1:5]_ResumptionTime"
"ATCint[1:5]_ResumptionMisses"
"Blank[1:5]_ResumptionMisses"
"None[1:5]_ResumptionMisses"

I just realised my error of labeling all my variables cat.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, Are those your actual column names, or does `[1:5]` represent that you have five such columns?

Comment: Yes, 5 such columns. Sorry for that.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, so you are starting with ~ 30 variable columns, plus 1 or more id columns and you want to end up with id columns  + "ResumptionTime" + "ResumptionMisses" + whether "ATCint", "Blank", or "None", and then the number, and the value? I'm just trying to clarify what you're actually dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Yep:

So I start with 30 variable columns, plus 1 ID variable.

I want to end up with:

ID + Trial ("whether ATCint1", or "Blank4"; separating the name from numbers doesn't matter ) +  "ResumptionTime" (contains value) + "ResumptionMisses" (contains value).

Does this make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94575/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-michael-anderson).